# External CA. Certificate chain validation

Tags: java, security, cryptography, certificate, bouncycastle

Suppose, there is an external CA. Let's say there is an URL and other config parameters.
In runtime I obtain a chain of certificates I need to validate using the CA.

So root certificate of the chain must be registered somehow in the CA. Also the CA handles CRL and some of the certificates in the chain could be revoked.

I have code like this

```
CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance(certificateType);
List<Certificate> certx = //list of certificates obtaining

//creating certification path (chain to be validated)
CertPath path = cf.generateCertPath(certx);
//validator creation. Algorithm to be defined
CertPathValidator validator = CertPathValidator.getInstance(certPathValidatorAlgorithm);

//get key store
KeyStore keystore = getKeyStore(keyStorePassword);
//get list of CRLs (certificate revoke list)
Collection<? extends CRL> crls = getCrls(cf);

PKIXParameters params = new PKIXParameters(keystore);
CertStore store = CertStore.getInstance(certStoreType, new CollectionCertStoreParameters(crls));
params.addCertStore(store);
//Validate will throw an exception on invalid chains.
PKIXCertPathValidatorResult r = (PKIXCertPathValidatorResult) validator.validate(path, params);
r.getTrustAnchor();
```

In case of local **cacert** and **CRLs** the logic works fine but the CA must be external.

So the getKeyStore() and getCrls() must be customized to access external CA server, establish trusted connection etc. etc.

Could you explain what config and protocols (CMP ?) to be used to support this? Is there something like this in e.g. BouncyCastle?

UPDATE: In fact it's not related to browsers and https at all.
In an XML we get a base64 encoded certificates chain. The certificates were issued by a CA. We need to validate the chain - send it to CA somehow and get Ok/Not Ok response or get a list of CRLs from the CA and provide mechanism to keep valid issued certificates as roots for our chains.

Comment: From your code I don't catch what you say about an external CA.
Are you generating new certificates ?
If not, then you only need the certifictes of the root CA and subordinates.

In order to validate a cert, you need a fresh CRL. 
Usually it is got doing an HTTP GET to the URL indicated in certificate extension called crlDistributionPoints

Comment: Didn't you see the skull and crossbones signs on your way to implementing revocation checking? It's a nightmare. Programmers have been known to chew off their arm to escape the task.

Comment: @Egl The CA generates certificates (sometimes chains). I get the chains and need to validate them. Ask CA whether the chain is valid and neither certificate was revoked.

Comment: @JamesReinstateMonicaPolk it's not related HTTPS access and have nothing related to browser.

Comment: Thanks, but I never mentioned HTTPS and browsers. To start with, a system of trust must have an anchor, in this case a root CA certificate. That anchor by definition can't retrieved securely over an insecure channel. Typically that means it is hard-coded into the system. Now, as for revocation, you'll need to deal with at least 3 commonly used systems: 1) no revocation system at all specified in the cert, 2) a CRL-based system with the URL identified as @egl has specified, and 3) an OCSP-based system with the URL in the cert. And I've just scratched the surface here.

Comment: Cool fact: The cert chain **that protects this very page** contains three certificates, each of which illustrates one of the three revocation schemes.